# How to check that the date has not been set for the past?

Tags: java, date, datetime

The following method should return `true` if the date is in future or in present. Like the date can be `10 May 2014` or `30 Apr 2014` but it cannot be set in the past. What is the correct way to check this ? This method gives out wrong results sometimes.

```
public boolean isDateOk(java.sql.Date date) {
    boolean isOk = false;
    if(new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() <= date.getTime()) isOk = true;
    return isOk;
}
```

Comment: Be specific. When does it give the wrong result?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt It gave for `2014-04-30`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use the `before` method

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29)

```
public boolean isDateOk(java.sql.Date date) {

  return (new java.util.Date ().before (date.getTime ()));

}
```

You could also use the Calendar class, using setTime 
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime(java.util.Date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime%28java.util.Date%29)

then compare using `get` for `YEAR` and `DAY_OF_YEAR`

```
 Calendar now = Calendar.getIntance ();
 Calendar dt = Calendar.getIntance ();
 dt.setTime (date.getIme());

 int nowYear = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 int dtYear = dt.get(Calendar.YEAR);
 int nowDOY = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
 int dtDOY = dt.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

 // do comparison
```

Comment: +1 but as a side note, beware that this compares the date AND time components, so two `Date` values for today may fail this comparison, just saying.

Comment: but I also want to return `true` for 2 date values for today

Comment: In that case I would use a Calendar class and verify that the year and day_of_year are within your requirements.

Comment: can you please provide a small example with your answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is (likely) that you retrieve the `java.sql.Date` from the database, in which case it won't have time information. The number of milliseconds returned by `getTime` then represents midnight in your timezone.

But when you create the GregorianCalendar, it will have hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.

So when you compare for the current day, the GregorianCalendar will always have milliseconds greater that the SQL Date.

To fix that, you can call the `set` method on the Calendar to zero out the hours, minutes, seconds  and milliseconds.
Better suggestion is to use DateMidnight in JodaTime, or if you have Java 8, it's new built in clone of JodaTime.